# List self nesting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming

## Question

I am trying to achieve a function that transforms a list into a second list with two sublist of itself. This function must do so by being called in a chain

i.e

```
[1,2,3] => [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

The function form should look something like this, where `fn` is the function i am looking for

```js
[1,2,3].map(x=>[x]).fn() //  => [[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2],[3]]]
```

Comment: well `result = [arr.clone(),arr.clone()]` would be more clean IMO

Comment: depend on your use case you may not need to clone `arr` btw

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `x=>[x,x]`. Clean, simple, functional. Do not complicate it.

Comment: Your 3rd question isn't very clear. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Bergi I think you might be right, will check when  I get home

Comment: @customcommander I guess I am trying to create an intermediary ‘let’ type assignment so I can refer further down the line to the state.

Comment: @cstml If you mean to declare an intermediate variable, just *do* declare a variable (using `const`). Or use [an IIFE to introduce a variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Named_constants) if you need the result to be an expression, but that's looking weird.

Comment: If you feel the need to duplicate a reference value, you are probably up to sth imperative. Maybe you need a pair tuple, because your code depends on the structure. I don't know if coding against structures is good or bad. Strutural typing is less sound than normative so I guess it should be avoided, unless it is a recursive structure, which tuples or arrays are apparently not.

Comment: @Bergi indeed it was as simple as x => [x,x]. I think the issue (going back) was trying to achieve it in line with (chaining it) to the other transformations, in abstract something similar to `[1,2,3,4]. x => [x,x]....` rather than `split([1,2,3,4).fn...`

Comment: @scriptum it might be the case that you are right. It might also be the case that I could potentially just split what I had in mind into another separate function (to keep it more cohesive) and then just compose the two results - which is probably what I should be doing

Comment: @cstml `const x = [1,2,3,4]; [x,x].fn(…)` or `(x=>[x,x].fn(…))([1,2,3,4])` or `(x=>[x,x])([1,2,3,4]).fn(…)`. For linear "piping", you might want to have a look at the [`|>` pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator)

Comment: @Bergi the "piping" or threading operator seems like a great idea, and is essentially what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Solution

> As suggested in the comments below

```js
[1,2,3,4].reduce(([l, r], x) => [[...l, x], [...r, x]], [[], []]) // => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: This might be what you've been looking for, but any `reduce` callback that uses `push` is not functional and I wouldn't call it elegant.

Comment: @Bergi that's interesting, how so? There is no side-effect here and the function is a total-function. What would make it functional or elegant?

Comment: `push` *is* a side effect. Sure, it's all contained in the `reduce`, but the callback by itself is not pure.

Comment: You could refer to `acc[0]` and `acc[1]` as "left" and "right" when destructuring the reduce accumulator. Then use the spread operator instead of push: `xs.reduce(([l, r], x) => [[...l, x], [...r, x]], [[], []])`. But this isn't necessarily better than `xs => [xs, xs]` or `xs => [[...xs], [...xs]]`

Comment: @Bergi, you are correct in that aspect - push is a side-effect, and the result is mutable as well (in its initial form)

Comment: @customcommander your solution is probably even more correct than the one posted because it doesn't involve any side effect - as @Bergi pointed out previously. The reason why I insist on the `.reduce` form is because it can be used arbitrarily within a chain of transformation, i.e. it can come after 3 other maps and 2 reduces or it can come after 1, without affecting the structure of the call itself ~ It can be easily chained

Comment: @customcommander if you want to add it to your answer, please let me know and I will remove from this one

Comment: @cstml can you please zoom out and show us the broader scope of your intention? this reeks of an XY problem. show us the code before this step and the code that will receive this `[arr, arr]` intermediate form you insist on creating.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options with plain JavaScript already.

If you just need two sublists out of one, this would be my preference:

```js
xs => [xs, xs]
```

If you need a variadic number of sublists, you can do:

```js
x => xs => Array(x).fill(xs)
```

---

Do you need to clone `xs`?

As long as you refrain from mutating you don't need to IMHO. When you do need to mutate just use the usual suspects such as `Array#map`, `Array#filter`, etc.

Comment: @customcommander very good to see the different options, especially the variadic option. Much thank you

Comment: @customcommander no worries. Is there a way to apply this function in a pipe? i.e `[1,2,3,4].map(x=>x).split(). ...`